# How can I reduce the size of my screenshots?

Tags: support, images

Often on Arqade, I find myself taking screenshots of my game window and drawing on them to show a more detailed explanation of my answer.

I use the Windows Photo app's Drawing editor to achieve these goals, but when uploading them using the image dialog, I keep getting the error message "Your image is too large to upload".

I find that before drawing, my images' sizes are about 500 KB. But after using the Photo Drawing Tool of Windows Photos, my image size increased to 2.57 mB, about 0.5 mB over the limit.

Mostly, all I do is import my image into Adobe Illustrator, and slowly reduce the image and artboard's size until they are *just* under 2 mB. But this is a lot of trial and error, and I would rather not go through it if I don't have to.

What can I do to reduce the size of my image?

Windows 10. Access to all Adobe CC tools, also access to Windows Photos and MS Paint.

Comment: Export it as JPG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of uploading your newly edited picture, save your copy in case you want to edit again in the future, then use something like Windows Snipping Tool to do a screen grab of what you are wanting to upload, and use that much smaller flat image.

Comment: Hooray, that worked! Clever and ingenious.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 cool, its what i do a lot myself. for work stuff as well :)